# 1004 No cells were found - Error Handling

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

Can anyone advise on how to handle a "no cells were found" error with the following code.  This is a part of a larger sub that may often return no values, however handling the error as follows (which works for many of my other scenarios) still returns "Run-time error '1004': No cells were found".  What am I doing wrong?

```
On Error GoTo Error_Exit_3
    Range("Q:Q").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
Error_Exit_3:
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading  [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 4):

What I Would do:

```
Dim RowsWithFormulas As Long

On Error Resume Next
RowsWithFormulas = Range("Q:Q").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Rows.Count
On Error GoTo 0
If RowsWithFormulas > 0 Then
    Range("Q:Q").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Damian, however this solution still errors in the same fashion if there are no cells with errors.  Also note my comment on BruceWayne's solution.

Comment: Is this code inside a loop? Otherwise there is no way this could give you an error. If it's part of a loop, use this: `RowsWithFormulas = 0` before the `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: It is not part of a loop no hence my confusion.  I have had to resolve the issue by writing a row to the data that will return and error in column Q so that there is always at least 1 record to find.  Not ideal but is a sufficient work around.

Comment: Where is giving you an error? The code on my answer counts the number of rows with error, if there are none, since it's withing the `On Error Resume Next` and because it is a `Long` variable, it will have a value of 0. Later will check the variable and if it's > 0 it will delete, else won't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set this as a Range:

```
Sub t()
Dim cellsWithErroringFormulas As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set cellsWithErroringFormulas = Range("Q:Q").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
On Error GoTo 0

If cellsWithErroringFormulas Is Nothing Then
   ' Do whatever
    MsgBox ("No formulas result in an error!")
    Exit Sub
ElseIf cellsWithErroringFormulas.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    cellsWithErroringFormulas.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete
    ' Now, if you call `cellsWithErroringFormulas` again, it will error since you removed all those references.
    ' So to be explicit, let's clear that variable.
    Set cellsWithErroringFormulas = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

I tweaked the variable name, just because you're not technically looking for rows with formulas, but rather cells with formulas that result in an error.  It's a little clunky here, so rename as desired. Just wanted to point that out.

Also, since I don't know what you plan on doing next, I added the `Set cellsWithErroringFormulas = Nothing`, since we can't use that reference after you delete the erroring rows.  You may not need that, but I just wanted to include to point that out also.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however this solution still errors in the same fashion if there are no cells with errors.  In this instance it errors upon `Set`.  Also with regards to the next action, this is the end of a sub followed only by `ActiveWorkbook.Save` and a MsgBox for completion.

Comment: @Daniel-Barnes it errors for you? It doesn't for me, that's odd

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link below. its already answered in this forum.
Also, Please visit the rules for this forum.. :)

[1004 Error: No cells were found, easy solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380886/1004-error-no-cells-were-found-easy-solution)

Comment: Many thanks, this post did not come up during my 60 minutes of searching.

Comment: welcome @DannyBarnes01, Dont forget to mark it as the answer for other user's reference.

Comment: Please disregard the above comments as this is the same method that I am currently using and still returns the error.

Comment: @DannyBarnes01 try to put the static range at your code.  --> ` Range("Q:Q")`